# Is the subset $\mathbb{Q}^2$ a dense subset of (M,d)?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $d:M \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $d(X,Y)=|x_1-y_1|+|x_2-y_2|$ where $X=(x_1,x_2), Y=(y_1,y_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. This is called the Manhattan metric. Plot the unit open ball B with center at the point (2,5), that is, $B=\{(x,y)| d((x,y),(2,5))<1\}$. Is the subset $\mathbb{Q}^2$ a dense subset of (M,d)? Give first your deinition of a dense subset of a metric space.

$\textbf{Definition:}$ A subset S of a metric space (M,d) is called open if for each $X \in S$ there is an open ball $B_{X,R}=\{ Y \in M|d(Y,X)<R\}$ with center at X for some readius R where $B_{X,R} \subseteq S$. By definition, all open balls are also open sets in any metric space. A subset T of a metric space is called closed if its complement is open.

$\textbf{Plot the unit open ball B with center at the point (2,5).}$

[image]

$\textbf{Is the subset $\mathbb{Q}^2$ a dense subset of (M,d)?}$

**I believe it is not but I do not know how to go about explaining that it is not**

$\textbf{Give first your deinition of a dense subset of a metric space.}$

When the topology of X is given by a metric, the closure $\bar{A}$ of A in X is the union of A and the set of all limits of sequences of elements in A (its limit points), $$\bar{A}=A \cup \{\,lim_n a_n: \forall n \geq 0, a_n \in A\}$$ Then A is dense in X if $\bar{A}=X$.

Comment: In the metric space $(M,d)$ you can restate the criterion for $\mathbb{Q}^2$ to be dense in the space quite simply:  Given a distance $\epsilon \gt 0$ and a point $(x,y)$, find a rational point within distance $\epsilon$ of $(x,y)$.

Comment: So it is possible?

Comment: The problem statement "give first your definition of a dense subset of a metric space" is where I think you got off track.  You went back to a general notion (closure of $A$ is all of $X$) and updated that only to have limit points characterized by sequences.  While this is a valid characterization, I think you will find the one I gave to be pretty easy to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My definition is that a subset $A$ is dense if every point $x$ in the space $X$ has a sequence $x_n \in A$ such that $x_n \to x$ (This is equivalent to $d(x,x_n) \to 0$ as $ n \to \infty$).

With this definition, $\mathbb{Q}^2$ is dense in $(M,d)$.

To prove this, we need to prove any $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, there exists sequences $(x_n,y_n)$ such that $(x_n,y_n) \to (x,y)$.

We know that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ with the euclidean metric. 
So for $x\in \mathbb{R}$, we get sequences $x_n \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $|x_n - x| < (\frac{1}{2})^{n}$, for $y\in \mathbb{R}$, we get sequences $y_n \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $|y_n - y| < (\frac{1}{2})^{n}$

$$ d( (x,y), (x_n,y_n) ) = |x-x_n| + |y-y_n| < 2 \cdot (\frac{1}{2})^{n} = (\frac{1}{2})^{n-1}$$
So $d( (x,y), (x_n,y_n) )\to 0$, in other words, $(x_n, y_n) \to (x,y)$.

So every point $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ has sequences $(x_n,y_n)$ in $\mathbb{Q}^2$ such that $(x_n, y_n \to (x,y)$ as $ n \to \infty$.